# Text not changing with a delay

Tags: java, swing

I have a label in a different class, and I am changing the text of this label in a action of another component. Anyways I have tried a delay on it like Thread.sleep(300) and even implementing my own method like

```
    private void waitTime(long WaitTime){
        long waitUntil = System.currentTimeMillis() + WaitTime;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() != waitUntil);
    }
```

It worked fine but the text didn't change before the delay. Is there an alternative delay that the text will actually change itself then delay?

```
if(frame.Index == 10){
        frame.label.setText("Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.");
        waitTime(3000);
        if(frame == null) return;
        System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Which GUI toolkit?  Swing, AWT, Java-FX, GWT, SWT, Android..?

Answer (score 2):

- You're putting the Swing event thread and thus the whole application to sleep with `Thread.sleep(...)`. So you don't want to use this on the Swing event thread (also known as the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT).
- Instead, use a Timer, not a `Thread.sleep(...)`
- An alternative is to throw a JOptionPane at the user with the desired message, and then to exit from your application when the JOptionPane returns. This way you are guaranteed that the user has at least seen the option pane and hopefully its message before the application exits.